# Calling Rest end point protected with TLS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, tls1.2

I have the below rest end point.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getData() {
        
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

In YML file

```
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    client-auth: need
    key-store: {keystore-path}
    key-store-password: {keystore-password}
    key-alias: alias-name
    key-store-type: JKS
```

With these proerties i am able to protect my Rest end point .When i try to call end point from POSTMAN
I get the expected error
**" Bad request .Combination of host and port requires TLS. "**
Which is fine and expected.

Now i need to write a client from java(non spring boot)
My doubt is do i need to import
Import Client Cert to Server jks File ? Is that the only step needed ?

Comment: As far as I know, you only need the certificate authorities of your certificate in Java cacerts file.

Comment: yes i am calling with https

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo what do you mean?

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking is backwards. The certificate should be on the server protecting the rest-point. To reach the servers end point, you need to have the same certificate in the client attempting to reach the end point. It sounds like you're very confused.

Comment: So you mean i need to import server certificate to client?